# Why can I not alias string[]?

Tags: c#, inheritance, alias

Why can I not alias `string[]`? I first tried inheriting `Array<string>` and `string[]` without success and then I tried aliasing it instead but that didn't work either.

Trying to inherit:

```
class Strings : Array<string> {} // "Array isn't generic"
class Strings : string[] {} // "Unexpected token"
```

Trying to use alias:

```
using strings = string[]; // "Unexpected token"
```

I want to be able to use `strings` instead of `string[]`.

Comment: Short answer: because language designers chose not to (or didn't think to) implement that feature.

Comment: Apart from the fact it's a horrible use of aliases (in my opinion, as all it really achieves is obscures things), the language doesn't allow it. The closest you can get would be to use `using strings = IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: and there wouldn't be much benefit I guess. You would still not be able to do `strings x = new strings();` because you have to define a size like `strings x = new string[10];`

Comment: You, intentionally, cannot derive from `Array`.  By design.

Comment: @RenéVogt then `using tenStrings = string[10];`?

Comment: no, because `string[10]` is not a type. (and the above example would look accordingly: `string[10] x = new string[10];` which is not valid c#).

Comment: In fact, an array of 10 strings is the same type as an array of 5 strings.  The type of an array is determined by the type it collects (string in this case) and it's rank (or dimension, 1 in this case).  That's why you say `string[] = new string[5]` - the type is `string[]` (a singly dimensioned array of strings).

Comment: Then, `strings s5 = new strings[5]` should be valid?